# Is there any reason to prefer nested models to pairwise comparisons? Or vice-versa?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, contrasts

I have a 2x2 design, where I am only really interested in one comparison. One level of one condition (let's call it A) effectively serves as a baseline and I am interested in the difference between the two levels of that condition (A) within either the first or second level of the other condition (B). As far as I know, there are two ways of potentially approaching this (using linear mixed models):

(i) running a model including the full experimental design as-is, keeping it as maximal as is justified by the design/model comparison, as is common in my field of linguistics, see  [Barr 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3881361/). Then, running post-hoc pairwise comparisons (corrected for multiple comparisons) and looking at the primary contrast of interest (using lsmeans/emmeans).

(ii) creating a nested model with the same random effects structure, coded with the following contrasts and model specification using lme4 (following the advice in [Schad et al. 2020](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749596X19300695)).

```
contrasts(data$A) <- (-0.5,+0.5)
contrasts(data$B) <- (+0.5,-0.5)
glmer(dep.var ~ B / A)
```

Now, presumably, given this structure I should get the main effect for B and the difference between the two levels of A nested within each level of B.

Is there any reason to prefer either methodology? Do both seem reasonable given this setup?

Comment: The first way, in my view, is preferable, because it does. not depend on how the factors are coded and is invulnerable to any mistakes you may make related to that. In your second approach, you do not have any random effects nor a link function (at least as you have described the situation), so it is way too fancy for what is needed and I'd be surprised it even works.

Comment: Thank you! I should have specified better, but in the second case I am assuming the same random effects structure as in the first as well as a logit link function. The other reasons you mention seem to be valid nonetheless, though and are probably reason enough to stick to the first method.